# Azure API Management - Service is beeing updated - availability during the update

Tags: azure-api-management

I need to do some changes in the Custom Domain of my Azure API Management instance in production.
When I do those changes in other environments, I saw that the instance is in a "Service is being updated" status for a few minutes.
I want to know if during this period of time the instance is still available to receive API requests or is it down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's still working properly.
But you are not able to do any changes like create APIs/operations, modify policies,...